# java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: while using charAt function

Tags: java

I want to get position of "," so i have used charAt function

below is the code

```
    public class JavaClass {

public static void main(String args[]){
    System.out.println("Test,Test".charAt(','));
}
}
```

but the problem is i am getting StringIndexOutOfBoundException can any body help me why i am getting this error

also i want to know that if ',' is not found than what the value will be return

error is below

```
      Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 44
at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
at JavaClass.main(JavaClass.java:5)
```

Comment: Read the `charAt` javadoc and read about primitive types. `','` is considered an `int` in that method call. `String index out of range: 44` should've given that away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `charAt` method expects an `int` representing the 0-based index where to look in the string.  Unfortunately for you, the `char` you passed in, `,` can be converted to an `int`, `44`, and there aren't 45 or more characters in your string, hence the `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Did you want to find the position of the `,` in your string?  Then `charAt` is the wrong method.  Try the [`indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29) method instead.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `indexOf`, rather than `charAt`
 `System.out.println("Test,Test".indexOf(","));`
`charAt` only returns the character at some position of the string; in this case it will be ascii code of ','

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the method [`String#charAt(int index)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29), you'll see that it takes in an `int` parameter. When you give `'` character, it takes the ASCII value of that(which is *44*) and tries to get the value at that index, which happens to be way more than the length of the String. And that is why you get the `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

You need to use the [`indexOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29) for this.

```
System.out.println("Test,Test".indexOf(','));
```

Answer (score 1):

charAt(int position) will take input parameter as integer. "," equivalent ascii value  44 because of this only your getting exception.